# Prove some set is closed in $(l^2,d_2)$, method verification

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I did the exact problem with $l^\infty$ space before, and I just want to know if a similar proof is valid for $l^2$ space too.

Consider $\displaystyle A = \{\{x_n\} \in l^2: \sum_{n\geq1}n^2 \vert x_n \vert^2 \leq 1\}$ in the $l^2$ space with the usual euclidean metric $d_2$ for sequence.

Show $A$ is closed. I am just going to give an idea of my proof and want to know if I missed anything.

Let $x \in \bar A$, then $\forall r > 0$ there is a $y \in B_r(x) \cap A$. Suppose to contradiction $x \notin A$ then $\sum_{n\geq1}n^2 \vert x_n \vert^2 > 1$. As the terms are non-negative, there is a $N$ so that $\sum_{n=1}^Nn^2 \vert x_n \vert^2 = k > 1$.

But this is a problem since for any $r>0$ there is a $y \in A$ so that $\sum_{n=1}^N\vert x_n - y_n\vert^2 < r^2$. Doing algebra:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N\vert x_n - y_n\vert^2 < r^2 \implies
\vert x_n - y_n \vert^2 < r^2 \implies \vert x_n \vert < \vert y_n \vert + r 
$$
$$
\implies n^2 \vert x_n\vert^2 < n^2 \vert y_n\vert^2 + n^22\vert y_n \vert r +n^2r^2 \text{ for all } n \geq 1
$$
Then the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{N} n^2\vert x_n\vert^2 < k$ if we choose $r$ to be small enough and contradiction is reached.

I also have a confusion. Our professor mentions we need to use the fact that the series is bounded (to be honest I don't know which series she refers to). I don't think I ever used this fact?

Comment: Update: This proof is wrong, as it relies on the wrong assumption that we can fix an r>0 small enough while at the same time assuming y is not changing